# Capture video stream on the web server with C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webcam

I build the ASP.NET MVC application that should access client's web cam in a browser and send the video stream to my web server and there some screenshots must be taken from that stream at a specific moment. I reviewed a lot of technologies but I can not figure out which matches.

The Flash is not suitable because I do not need a separate Flash media server. The WebRTC seems like establishing peer-to-peer connection between clients omitting web srver (I do not see how to capture WebRTC video stream on a web server). IIS Media service require some streaming encoders and it is not about working directly with client's web cam.

And for Silverlight I only found examples how to use it as video player and screenshot maker, but not a broadcaster. But I must make screenshots on the server, not in the client.

So I lost my way.

Can anybody prompt me the right direction?

Comment: What will this software be used for?

Comment: maybe one of these links is useful for you. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/528929/Capture-images-using-web-camera-in-ASP-NET-4-5 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2265/Webcam-Web-Service http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2483/Dynamic-Webcam-Image

Comment: This is a security application. No, these links describe how to send prepared screenshots. But I can not afford clients to decide what to send and when. I need a pure videostream and only security logic decides when to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can capture a WebRTC video/audio on the server. Just provide a WebRTC client (running on the server) that communicates with the other WebRTC clients. You may want to check the open source C client by Google (https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/). However, this means that you do not need ASP.NET at all. You can adapt the aforementioned client and copy them to a specific directory and process them with ASP.NET from there.

Comment: Thank you for your responce. Unfortunately I do not know C and all it's environment and have no idea how to adapt all that stuff to my project. I will better look at the Flash Media Server direction in the last resort